# Initialization of variables in GMP

Tags: c++, gmp, arbitrary-precision

According to the manual of GMP, "The functions for integer arithmetic assume that all integer objects are initialized. You do that by calling the function mpz_init."

For example,

```
int main(){
    mpz_t n1, n2, result;
    mpz_init_set_str(n1, "465860", 10);
    mpz_init_set_str(n2, "167", 10);
    mpz_init(result);
    mpz_mod(result, n1, n2);
    mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, result);
    return 0;
}
```

if you remove `mpz_init(result);` from the code above, the compiler will produce an segmentation fault error. So, my question, what exactly is difference between these two type of definition: `mpz_t result` and `mpz_init(result)`. Why is `mpz_init` also required?

Comment: Don't forget mpz_clear! Or use the C++ interface, which does all the magic for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mpz_t result` only declares a variable.  The type `mpz_t` is a typedef for `struct __mpz_struct`.  This structure contains three variables which are initialized by `mpz_init()`.  Hope that helps.